# TypeError: this.props.weather is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-promise

I'm working on an app that will help me fetch a five day weather forecast for any city using openweathermap.org, However, i get the above error in the browser whenever i call a function renderWeather in the WeatherList container as shown in my code snippets below.

This file is the index.js where i imported redux promise

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Code for the weather_list container is below

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class WeatherList extends Component{

renderWeather(cityData){
  return(
    <tr>
      <td>{cityData.city.name}</td>
    </tr>
  );

}

  render(){
    return(
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Temperature</th>
          <th>Pressure</th>
          <th>Humidity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    weather: state.weather
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

Code for the search_bar container is below

```js
import React, {Component}from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {fetchWeather} from '../actions/index';

class SearchBar extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {term: ''};
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

onInputChange(event){
  console.log(event.target.value);
  this.setState({term: event.target.value});
}

onFormSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // we need to go and fetch weather data!
  this.props.fetchWeather(this.state.term);
  this.setState({term: ''});
}

  render(){
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} className="input-group">
        <input
          placeholder="Get a five-day forecast in your favorite cities"
          className="form-control"
          value={this.state.term}
          onChange={this.onInputChange} />
        <span className="input-group-btn">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
        </span>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({fetchWeather:fetchWeather}, dispatch)
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Code for the app component is shown below

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../containers/search_bar.js';
import WeatherList from '../containers/weather_list.js';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar />
        <WeatherList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code for the weather reducer is shown below

```js
import {FETCH_WEATHER} from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_WEATHER:
      //return state.concat([action.payload.data]);
      return ([action.payload.data, ...state])
  }
  return state;
}
```

Code for index.js in the reducers folder is shown below

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import WeatherReducer from './reducer_weather';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  weather: WeatherReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Code for the action creator in the actions folder is shown below

```js
import axios from 'axios';
const API_KEY = '03d17752ca362bc60ca7df94aac228a6';
const ROOT_URL =`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?appid=${API_KEY}`;

export const FETCH_WEATHER = 'FETCH_WEATHER';

export function fetchWeather(city){
  const url = `${ROOT_URL}&q=${city},us`;
  const request = axios.get(url);

  console.log('Request:', request);

  return{
    type: FETCH_WEATHER,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

Finally, an image showing the error in the broswer is below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbwqL.png)

Any assistance on how to go about the error is much appreciated

Comment: In WeatherList you can try `{this.props.weater && this.props.weather.map(..` your code this will not cause to execute code when you have `undefined` variable

Answer (score 1):

Initially this.props.weather will be undefined so you need to do conditional check before doing .map like in two ways

```
this.props.weather && this.props.weather.map
```

OR

```
Array.isArray(this.props.weather) && this.props.weather.map
```

Also when doing .map you need to pass weather data to renderWeather method because it expects data but you are not passing the data to it in .map

Change

```
{this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
```

To

```
 {Array.isArray(this.props.weather) && this.props.weather.map(item => this.renderWeather(item))}
```

Also set unique key to tr element here

```
renderWeather(cityData){
  return(
    <tr key={cityData.city && cityData.city.id}> //if you do not have unique id then use index as key
      <td>{cityData.city && cityData.city.name}</td>
    </tr>
  ); 
}
```

or if your data doesn't contain unique id then use index as key

```
 {Array.isArray(this.props.weather) && this.props.weather.map((item, index) => this.renderWeather(item, index))}
```

Also set unique key to tr element here

```
renderWeather(cityData, index){
  return(
    <tr key={"city-"+index}> //if you do not have unique id then use index as key
      <td>{cityData.city && cityData.city.name}</td>
    </tr>
  ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because `this.props.weather` is `undefined` thus calling the `.map()` function on an `undefined` will throw you the error. You can add the validation ahead to make sure it only call the `.map()` when it is an array (when the data comes in).

You can add:

```
Array.isArray(this.props.weather) && ...
```

Do the changes here:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class WeatherList extends Component{

renderWeather(cityData){
  return(
    <tr>
      <td>{cityData.city.name}</td>
    </tr>
  );

}

  render(){
    return(
      <table className="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Temperature</th>
          <th>Pressure</th>
          <th>Humidity</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {Array.isArray(this.props.weather) && this.props.weather.map(this.renderWeather)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    weather: state.weather
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```